# \item as static current date(time)

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

I want to create a list (`\itemize`) where the labels of each `\item` is a (static) representation of the time the bullet point is made. (I understand that there would have to be a better definition of this "now", e.g. first compiling with that item in the document etc. but I want to leave this open. Essentially, I want to add bullet points and have the date(time) saved when the bullet point was written.

Is there any way of achieving the below without manually typing the dates?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{Name}
\title{Collection of thoughts with (date and time)}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[2020-07-15 16:22] \textbf{Point one} \lipsum[2] % written on Jul 15, 16:22
        \item[2020-07-16 08:42] \textbf{Point two} \lipsum[3] % written on Jul 16, 08:42
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

As a comment suggests this might be on the editor-level, the solution would ideally work in TeXstudio and/ or Overleaf.

Comment: Some editors have menu entries to write the date and time at the moment of invocation. I think what you want is more a matter of your editor of choice than TeX, that was thought for typesetting. Probably you are better served with a note taking application, a log recorder or a diary. I use for this purpose Notepad2-mod, that does what you want, but it save in pure text.

Comment: You might delete or add a item half way, TeX is unable to record such change.